# Search query array value binding not working

Tags: php, arrays, search, full-text-search

I'm working on a search query and i hit a little bump... So as you see in the code below, i'm adding values to a array to execute it later in the script, but it's not really working... So when i var_dumped all of this, it returned like it is supposed to but the :q was not changed to the value which was entered in the link.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$columnsQuery = [];
$values       = [];

if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']))
{
$columnsQuery[] = " WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (':q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
$values[":q"]   = $_GET['q'];
}

$fullQuery = $query . implode(" ", $columnsQuery)
   . " ORDER BY id DESC"
   . " LIMIT {$paginator->getLimitSQL()}";

$getArticles = $db->prepare($fullQuery)->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM articles";

    $columnsQuery   = [];
    $values         = [];

    if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']))
    {
        $columnsQuery[]     = " WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (':q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
        $values["q"]        = $_GET['q'];           // TRY WITHOUT COLON
    }

    $fullQuery = $query . implode(" ", $columnsQuery)
        . " ORDER BY id DESC"
        . " LIMIT {$paginator->getLimitSQL()}";

    $getArticles = $db->prepare($fullQuery)->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use colon in the place of `$values["q"] = $_GET['q'];`

```
$query          = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$columnsQuery   = [];
$values         = [];

if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']))
{
    $columnsQuery[]     = " WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (':q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
    $values["q"]        = $_GET['q'];           // TRY WITHOUT COLON
}

$fullQuery = $query . implode(" ", $columnsQuery)
    . " ORDER BY id DESC"
    . " LIMIT {$paginator->getLimitSQL()}";

$getArticles = $db->prepare($fullQuery)->execute($values);
```

Comment: yea copied from your answer..@Poiz. But It is known to me there should be no colon..by the way if you have issue i can delete it.

Comment: No errors, this is from the var_dumping the query and values

string(177) "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (':q' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,5" 

array(1) { ["q"]=> string(3) "tja" }

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$values = array();
if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
  $query .= " WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (q IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
  $db->bindParam(':q', $_GET['q']);
}

$fullQuery = $query  . " ORDER BY id DESC" . " LIMIT {$paginator->getLimitSQL()}"
$getArticles = $db->prepare($fullQuery)->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a while i figured it out, You're not supposed to use parameters while binding in the query, and like @Poiz pointed out i shouldnt use colons in the array either

Thx to everyone who tried helping :)